# Select children (or successor) elements as content

Tags: jquery, tooltipster

In Tooltipster, can something like `self.next()` or `self.children()` be used as `data-tooltip-content`?

If an element with `class="tooltip"` points to a named element, that named element will be the tooltip’s content. Cool. Below, the list of features pops up when the model number is moused-over.

Is there a way to do this without giving a separate `id` to each content element? Can I tell Tooltipster to just use the next element?

```
<style type="text/css">
    .tooltip-content {display:none}
    .tooltipster-base .tooltip-content {display:block}
</style>

<span class="tooltip" data-tooltip-content="#tc1">Model 2000X</span>
<ul class="tooltip-content" id="tc1"> 
    <li>Red</li>
    <li>Platinum</li>
    <li>32 cu in.</li>
</ul>

<span class="tooltip" data-tooltip-content="#tc2">Model 3000X</span>
<ul class="tooltip-content" id="tc2"> 
    <li>Blue</li>
    <li>Gold</li>
    <li>64 cu in.</li>
</ul>
```

Or, what about children instead of successor? Here the content is inside the `tooltip` span instead of after it:

```
<span class="tooltip" data-tooltip-content="#tc1">Model 2000X
   <ul class="tooltip-content" id="tc1"> 
       <li>Red</li>
       <li>Platinum</li>
       <li>32 cu in.</li>
   </ul>
</span>
```

For what I need, either—or even something similar—would be fine. I just want to avoid naming all the content elements, and instead use position to identify content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
$('.tooltip').tooltipster({
  functionInit: function(instance, helper){
    instance.content($(helper.origin).next().detach());
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5xqqmrt6/33/

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe. Can you say just a bit about what is going on there? (The fiddle doesn’t have this in it.)

Comment: I see. http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/#callback_arguments. And tooltipster objects are jQuery objects, so we can use jQuery .next(). etc. I don’t see exactly why .detach() is used, but this puts me on the right path. Thanks Evan.

Comment: Sorry, the jsfiddle seems to have not been saved properly, this is really weird. If you don't detach, the element will stay in the DOM until the first appearance of the tooltip, you don't want that.

Comment: I see. Thanks Evan. (Oh, do up-vote the question if you think it’s appropriate. Cheers.)

Comment: Well ok, this is basic javascript but at least the question was well asked. I've updated the fiddle. Feel free to accept the answer, thank you

Comment: Oops. Thought I had. There you go!